# Java Generic member type erased in subclass?

Tags: java, variables, generics, inheritance, member

I have a class with below member:

```
public  class BaseContainer {
    protected LinkedHashMap<Enum, MyClass> places;
}
```

And a subclass where I use the protected member :

```
public class NullContainer extends BaseContainer {
    public MyClass getSelectedPlace() {
        return places.values().iterator().next(); 
    }
}
```

And I get (In netbeans):
error: incompatible types
required : MyClass
found : Object

Why do I need to cast now? What happened with the type info? Was it erased just because of inheritance? What am I doing wrong.

Seems to be a bug in my java compiler then. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. It'll make it much easier to help you. (The code you've shown compiles fine for me.)

Comment: Cannot reproduce - works fine for me. (Probably unrelated, but you have a raw type with `Enum` - make it `Enum<?>`, perhaps).

Comment: What you've shown looks fine.  Are you sure you don't have some other variable `places` defined somewhere?

Comment: Ok thanks Andy, I guess this has to do something with my netbeans maven project then, I thought this is some Java issue, than type info gets lost during inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

So finally I think I found the answer to be a bug in jdk1.7.0_51 (which I am using). 
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8061736
However there are oppinions that this is not a bug (see the end of bugreport):

The superclasses (respectively, superinterfaces) of a raw type are the erasures of the superclasses (superinterfaces) of any of its parameterized invocations. So as GenList is a raw type the return type of method getAValue is not A or String but Object. Which corresponds with javac's output.

(I really think this is rather a bug, because all taht this achieves is that now I am forced to cast every occurence of this member field in all subclasses, which just doesn't make any sense...)

Comment: That comment is not applicable here because you didn't use any raw types.